# Dictionary Key:Value removal and re insertion into a list or something

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm attempting to make a hangman game for practice. I've wrote the function to get the random word and a function to pair those characters up with there index. Wondering if the user guess a correct character is there a way to reference the dictionary, and output the character to an empty list at the correct index? Code I Have so far:

```
import random
import sys

def hangman():
    print("Welcome to Hangman\n")
    answer = input("Would you like to play? yes(y) or no(n)")
    if answer is "y":
        print("Generating Random Word...Complete")
        wordlist = []
        with open('sowpods.txt', 'r') as f:
            line = f.read()
            line = list(line.splitlines())
            word = list(random.choice(line))
            Key = matchUp(word)


    else:
        sys.exit()

def matchUp(word):
    list = []
    for x in word:
        list.append(word.index(x))
    newDict = {}
    newDict = dict(zip(word, list))
   return newDict

hangman()
```

Comment: Can you supply the logic, step by step? It's hard to understand from introduction words.

Comment: So, I'd like the user to guess a  character in the random generated word. If this character is in the word, then I'd like a function to reference the dictionary I created and use the character and its index to add that character to a list at that specified index so the user can see where their correct guess went.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So like this? You can skip the whole dictionary thing...

```
a = "_" * len(word)

def letter_check(letter):
    if letter in word:
        a[word.index(letter)] = letter
        # possibly print 'a' here
    else:
        # function for decrement tries here
```

EDIT: Ooops... I forgot about potential repeated letters... um... how about this:

```
a = "_" * len(word)

def letter_check(letter):
    if letter in word:
        for x, y in enumerate(word):
            if letter == y:
                a[x] = letter
    else:
        # function for decrement tries here
```

Comment: a = "_" * len(word), Whats this line doing?

Comment: It's making a representation of the empty word, with a length of `word` with a blank (`_`) for each letter. (to start off with) Edit: hope that makes sense

Comment: I added a fix for repeated letters

Comment: Did you move, a = "_" * len(word) outside of the function on purpose?

Comment: Well, if it was in the function, it would reset your progress on the word every time you called `letter_check`...